# angularjs ui.router is throwing Error: Unexpected request: GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement AngularJS Routing Using UI-Router. I have index.html file which is trying to load the partial productListView.html using app.js as javascript but i am seeing Error: Unexpected request: GET productListView.html in my console. Any help would be appreciated.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Acme Product Management</title>
    <!--Style Sheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="productManagement">
    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
    <!--Library Scripts-->
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <!--Application Script-->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!--Services-->
    <script src="common/services/common-services.js"></script>
    <script src="common/services/productResource.js"></script>
    <script src="common/services/productResourceMock.js"></script>
    <!--Product Controllers-->
    <script src="products/productListCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('productManagement',['common-services',
                                        'productResourceMock',
                                        'ui.router'])
           .config(['$stateProvider',
                    '$urlRouterProvider',
                    function($stateProvider,
                             $urlRouterProvider){

                    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/products');

                    $stateProvider
                        .state('productList', {
                            url:         '/products',
                            templateUrl: 'products/productListView.html',
                            controller:  'ProductListCtrl'
                        });
                    }]
           );
})();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you dd a '/' at the start of the templateUrl and check, like `templateUrl: '/products/productListView.html'`

Comment: @Arulkumar. I tried its not working either.

Comment: Can you re-check once, after clear the cache.

Comment: I cleared cache and did hard reload but still seeing the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, you must change: `$httpBackend.whenGET(/app/).passThrough();` in `productResourceMock.js` file

Comment: Yes you are right, we need to bypass all the request which is in our app directory, in this error case is "productListView.html". I think this answer should be accepted as a solution.

Comment: pluralsight - angularjs line of business applications.. great course..highly recommend it  :)

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly icluding Javascript files that are meant for testing in your HTML file. The error you are seeing comes from the "mock" version of HTTPBackend that is used in unit tests.

You should remove lines like these from the HTML:

```
<script src="js/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="common/services/productResourceMock.js"></script>
```

Comment: @@Sunil. Those files are not for unit testing, I am trying to mock the web-service with those files. can you tell me what is the correct way to include those JavaScript files.

Comment: I can't comment about  `productResourceMock.js`, but `angular-mocks.js` is intended primarily for unit testing. If you're trying to use it as a pseudo back end, you would have to go and augment all of your application code to tell it how to respond to each query. That's why you get the error message you're getting, the mock `$httpbackEnd` was not told to expect or how to respond to any requests.

Comment: Also, by including `angular-mocks.js` you're including mocked versions of more than just the `$httpBackend` service. You can read more about what else is mocked [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock).